# autoupdate/autopopulate picklist

Tags: picklist

Is it possible to autoupdate or autopopulate a picklist? I have a picklist with users name. If a user changes his name, the new user name should be displayed in the picklist and the old name should be gone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. That said, user lookups are designed for exactly that purpose and are MUCH more robust.  Using a picklists for people is a very common design choice I see that can end up causing TONS of headaches down the line.  You'll be very happy if you fix that sooner than later.

If you want to ensure users only pick certain users you can add a lookup filter to restrict which users are selectable.

Comment: THanks Ralph, I'll use the lookup as it seems to be a better option.